# .htaccess rewrite rule only if file not found and only one /directory

Tags: .htaccess

This is an extract of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /a/?s=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I want it to apply only to directories in the site's root /something /whatever /example etc. not to /something/a or /whatever/b

How can I add this extra rule so it's more precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the expression from `^(.*)$` to `^([^/]+)/?$`, which means: the entire thing must not contain a `/` unless it's at the end. Note that the URI is stripped of its leading slash when you match against it in htaccess files.